# CREATE TABLE fails despite preceding DROP TABLE statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am attempting to support another developer's CodeIgniter framework php which uses mysql.

The code does the following (among other things before and after):

```
$sql_case_00_4 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS top_domains_video_image_audio_detected";
$this->db->query($sql_case_00_4);

$sql_case_00_5 = "CREATE TABLE top_domains_video_image_audio_detected (domain_name varchar(255),genId varchar (12),trackingId int)";
$this->db->query($sql_case_00_5);
```

On occasion mysql generates the following error which we log: "Query error: Table 'top_domains_video_image_audio_detected' already exists". This is the only place in the code where the table is being generated (or used at all really).

One possibility I was thinking was that a race condition could occur if two requests attempted to create the table at the same time.

But that seems rare as there aren't many who are querying this server, unless perhaps two back-to-back actions by the same user could cause two simultaneous requests.

I'm not 100% sure, but I am guessing that the query() function does block, thus preventing CREATE from being called during the DROP.

Is there another possibility here that could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Try both queries at one go. `$sql_case_00_4 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS top_domains_video_image_audio_detected; CREATE TABLE top_domains_video_image_audio_detected (domain_name varchar(255),genId varchar (12),trackingId int)";`

Comment: Interesting. Doing that caused the site to hang for some reason. I think I may need some sort of "multi query" type function but I'm not sure which one to use. Note that doing the two commands together from mysql itself (same user) works fine.

Comment: We're using the mysql driver and not the mysqli driver, and apparently there is no mysql driver function that allows doing two queries together.

Comment: @vmayer mysql driver is deprecated (and considered insecure). You should try changing to the mysqli driver. If you're using a framework as it looks like you are, then you shouldn't have too many difficulties transitioning.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest combining both queries as mentioned by phpfreak or checking to ensure that the db user you're using has DROP privileges.  (Not sure if your web app would throw an exception at that point or silently fail).

Answer (score 0):

$sql_case_00_4 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS top_domains_video_image_audio_detected; CREATE TABLE top_domains_video_image_audio_detected (domain_name varchar(255),genId varchar (12),trackingId int)";